# Prime ideals lying over a given prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

**Question:** Consider $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $B=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$. Let $I=7\mathbb{Z}$ be the prime ideal in $A$. I want to find a prime ideal in $B$ lying over $I$. That is, I need to find a prime ideal $J \subseteq B$ such that $J \cap A=I$.

I have tried the obvious choices: if I take $J=IB$, then $J \cap A=I$ but $IB$ is not prime. If I take $J$ to be the ideal generated by $\sqrt{-3}$ in $B$, then $J$ is prime but $J \cap A \neq I$. **What should $J$ be ?**

In general, is there any trick to do this type of problem?

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So suppose our prime ideal was generated by some $a+\sqrt{-3}b$ with $a,b\in \mathbb
 Z$. Then, we would need $a^2 + 3b^2 = (a+b\sqrt{-3})(a-b\sqrt{-3})$ to be divisible by $7$ since it is in $\mathbb Z \cap J = I$. We can take $a=2,b=1$ to get $7$ exactly.

So you should guess that $J = (2+\sqrt{-3})$ (or $(2-\sqrt{-3}$) ). Now try and show that these are prime ideals using the norm.

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't thought we can consider elements of the form $a^2+3b^2$.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by show these are prime using the norm? Is being prime has anything to do with the norm?

Comment: Well, if an ideal was composite, it's burn couldn't be prime, right?

Comment: Burn = norm, typo.